# Worldwide Reference System

Tags: google-earth

Is there a way to click on a location in Google Earth and have it identify the Worldwide Reference System (WRS) 2 path and row associated with Landsat imagery?

I have been attempting without success to locate an ArcGIS 10 shapefile that displays paths and rows.  (I have posted a similar question more-or-less specific to ArcGIS on their forum).

Earthexplorer displays latitude and longitude if I simply click on the Google map with the mouse cursor, but does not seem to display the path and row.

http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Nor can I find a way to identify paths and rows by pointing and clicking in USGS Global Visualization Viewer although I am new to that site.

http://glovis.usgs.gov/

I have found a static map of paths and rows here:

http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/about/wrs2.gif

However, I would prefer to find a site that returns paths and rows if I simply point and click on a map.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: Hi! This question fits better in http://gis.stackexchange.com. I flagged it and asked to be moved over there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the GIS shape files:

http://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_wrs-2_shapefile.php

I am not sure why I overlooked this link earlier.  It was not the first or second hit that Google returned, but it was the third hit returned by my latest attempt.

Note that there also seem to be KML files at the link above.  I am not certain, but I think those files perhaps can be loaded into Google Earth to display the paths and rows in that software.

I will try both approaches in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you mentioned (https://landsat.usgs.gov/tools_wrs-2_shapefile.php) there is two KML files (only for WRS-2):
-One with the boundaries of the scenes (a path/row refers to a scene).
-One with the centers of each scene. This one is particularly useful when there is more than one scene overlapping the region of interest.

The overlapping regions have a better time resolution as far as the satellite visit the overlapped region before the revisit time has passed.

There is also shapefiles showing the ascending and descending orbits for WRS-1 and WRS-2.